# Get device token in distribution

Tags: objective-c, ios, push

In development, I add the code as below to get the token at the log

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    [self sendDeviceTokenToRemote:deviceToken]; // send the token to your server
}
```

But in distribution, how can I get the device token?

Thanks